# Curl file upload -F post request in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl, post

I'm not sure how to implement post request equivalent to this curl request:

```
curl -F=@file.json https://www.example.com/?id=some_id
```

I tried creating an NSDictionary equivalent my json,

```
jsondata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                              options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                 error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/?id=some_id"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsondata];
```

But something is wrong as it doesn't work. Pls help if you know what's the problem.